# How to write to XML file from SQL Server based on conditions

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

A little background, this is my first post but I have gotten many solutions from this site. If this is a repost, I apologize, but I haven't been able to find a good solution and am having a difficult time piecing bits from other places to get what I want.

I have found some solutions around (on here and on Google) regarding reading/exporting XML from SQL. But I have a specific question: How do I *modify* an XML formatted file from a table?

I have a temp table that holds all of the findings from my SQL 2012 STIG query. I have been exporting it to a .csv, but I want to also add functionality to export the findings to an .xml file.

Here's an example of the .xml:

```
<CHECKLIST>
  <ID>
    <SOME_DATA>
        <ID_ATTRIBUTE>ID_Num</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>123</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </SOME_DATA>
    <SOME_DATA>
        <ID_ATTRIBUTE>REF</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>54</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </SOME_DATA>
    <STATUS>Not_Reviewed</STATUS>
    <FINDING_DETAILS></FINDING_DETAILS>
    <COMMENTS></COMMENTS>
  </ID>
  <ID>
    <SOME_DATA>
        <ID_ATTRIBUTE>ID_Num</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>124</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </SOME_DATA>
    <SOME_DATA>
        <ID_ATTRIBUTE>REF</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>145</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </SOME_DATA>
    <STATUS>Not_Reviewed</STATUS>
    <FINDING_DETAILS></FINDING_DETAILS>
    <COMMENTS></COMMENTS>
  </ID>
```

What I want to do is something to the effect of:

```
IF <CHECKLIST/ID/SOME_DATA/ID_ATTRIBUTE> = 'ID_Num'
   AND <CHECKLIST/ID/SOME_DATA/ID_DATA> = @variable
      FROM 'e:\stuff\test.xml'
SET <CHECKLIST/ID/COMMENTS> = @comments_variable
```

I realize that the above code block is a complete incorrect iteration of query, but I hope you get what I'm trying to do.

I appreciate any help.

Custom stored procedures (not native to MS SQL) are *HIGHLY* discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the value of the COMMENTS node with a variable like so:

```
declare @x xml = '<CHECKLIST>
  <ID>
    <SOME_DATA>
        <ID_ATTRIBUTE>ID_Num</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>123</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </SOME_DATA>
    <SOME_DATA>
        <ID_ATTRIBUTE>REF</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>54</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </SOME_DATA>
    <STATUS>Not_Reviewed</STATUS>
    <FINDING_DETAILS></FINDING_DETAILS>
    <COMMENTS></COMMENTS>
  </ID>
  <ID>
    <SOME_DATA>
        <ID_ATTRIBUTE>ID_Num</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>124</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </SOME_DATA>
    <SOME_DATA>
        <ID_ATTRIBUTE>REF</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>145</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </SOME_DATA>
    <STATUS>Not_Reviewed</STATUS>
    <FINDING_DETAILS></FINDING_DETAILS>
    <COMMENTS></COMMENTS>
  </ID>
  </CHECKLIST>';



declare @AttributeData int = 123;
declare @Comments varchar(100) = 'yak yak yak...';

set @x.modify('insert text{sql:variable("@Comments")} into (/CHECKLIST/ID/SOME_DATA[ID_ATTRIBUTE = "ID_Num"][ATTRIBUTE_DATA = sql:variable("@AttributeData")]/../COMMENTS)[1]');

select @x;
```

As far as reading the xml data from disk into a variable, its probably not advisable to do in t-sql, but I have used this on occasion:

```
declare @x xml;

set @x = (
    select * from openrowset(bulk 'C:\temp\yak.xml', single_blob
) as d;
```

More info on that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx

Writing the xml variable to a file is also a task I would probably do elsewhere (SSIS, console app, etc.) but it is possible in t-sql:

```
create table dbo.xStage (x xml);

insert into dbo.xStage(x)
    select @x;

declare @cmd varchar(max),
        @fileName varchar(max)

set @fileName = 'c:\temp\myXML.xml'

set @cmd = 'bcp "select x from YourDB.dbo.xStage" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T -S' + @@servername

execute master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

More info on using bcp to export xml here: https://sqlsouth.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/export-xml-from-sql-server-using-bcp/

Comment: Can I easily export to a file from the @x variable? Or would it need to be from a table using bcp?

Comment: Yes, if this is a one time thing you can just write the file from t-sql but SSIS is probably the place to do this if its a core component of your sys.

Comment: I sent it to a global temp table then exported back to an .xml file via BCP. This isn't a regular thing. It's an annual thing and I have an entire 7000k+ query to check the system for vulnerabilities (180+ items). I just wanted to export it to .xml format to which the DISA STIG Viewer we use can read (because that's ultimately what our IA imports it as into their system). I was able to work it, based on your reply, to what I wanted. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a general-purpose programming solution especially since the XML file does not originally reside inside a database such as in a BLOB field. SQL is a special-purpose language designed primarily to manage (update, append, delete) and retrieve database content in [DML and DDL](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=ddldml.php) procedures. It is not advised to make it do more such as handling files externally.

But for your needs, practically any general-purpose language including Java, C#, Perl, PHP, Python, and VB can dynamically parse and manipulate XML content. Below is a VBA macro example using your everyday MS Excel. In fact, it uses another declarative special-purpose lanaguage, [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), which is primarily designed to modify, re-structure, and re-format XML documents. And yes most programming languages maintain XSLT processors:

**XSLT** (*save as .xsl file and referenced in below macro; can also be embedded as string in macro*)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:param name="var" select="123"/>

 <!-- IdentityTransform -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="COMMENTS">
   <COMMENTS>
    <xsl:if test="../SOME_DATA/ID_ATTRIBUTE='ID_Num' and ../SOME_DATA/ATTRIBUTE_DATA = $var">
       yak yak yak...
    </xsl:if>
   </COMMENTS>
 </xsl:template>    

</xsl:transform>
```

To change variable and comments, simply adjust above param value '123' and `yak yak yak` node text.

**Excel macro** (*using Microsoft's [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object*)

```
Sub TransformXML()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim xmldoc As Object, xsldoc As Object, newdoc As Object

    Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xsldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set newdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    ' LOAD XML
    xmldoc.async = False
    xmldoc.Load "e:\stuff\test.xml"

    ' LOAD XSL
    xsldoc.async = False
    xsldoc.Load "e:\stuff\XSLT-SCRIPT.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM
    xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xsldoc, newdoc
    newdoc.Save "e:\stuff\Output.xml"

    MsgBox "XML successfully modified!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL OUTPUT"

    Set xmldoc = Nothing
    Set xsldoc = Nothing
    Set newdoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Set xmldoc = Nothing
    Set xsldoc = Nothing
    Set newdoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub    
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CHECKLIST>
    <ID>
        <SOME_DATA>
            <ID_ATTRIBUTE>ID_Num</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>123</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </SOME_DATA>
        <SOME_DATA>
            <ID_ATTRIBUTE>REF</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>54</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </SOME_DATA>
        <STATUS>Not_Reviewed</STATUS>
        <FINDING_DETAILS>
        </FINDING_DETAILS>
        <COMMENTS>yak yak yak...</COMMENTS>
    </ID>
    <ID>
        <SOME_DATA>
            <ID_ATTRIBUTE>ID_Num</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>124</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </SOME_DATA>
        <SOME_DATA>
            <ID_ATTRIBUTE>REF</ID_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>145</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </SOME_DATA>
        <STATUS>Not_Reviewed</STATUS>
        <FINDING_DETAILS>
        </FINDING_DETAILS>
        <COMMENTS/>
    </ID>
</CHECKLIST>
```

Comment: I like it, long live xslt!   +1

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I just wanted something to export at the end of my query. This isn't a normal thing (once a year for a vulnerability scan). But I am going to keep this for future reference!. Thanks for the reply.